# Powershell: How to use Format-Table with xml attributes

Tags: powershell

I have some webserver logs in this format

```
<result offset='0'>
    <field k='_raw'><v xml:space='preserve' trunc='0'>2014-04-29 04:36:14 W3SVC2 <sg h='1'>192.168</sg>.30.54 GET /HTTP1.1 - 443 - <sg h='1'>192.168</sg>.35.253 - - - 404 1285 14 0</v></field>
    <field k='_time'>
```

I would like to know how to use format table for attributes

so that I have a column for  as "raw" and so on. At the moment the result from below returns
{field, field, field...|

```
$x = | Format-Table -Property field <-- how to specify attribute
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a calculated property.

```
$x | Format-table @{l="k";e={$_.field.k}}
```

Be sure to provide a working xml sample, valid code (`= |` is not valid code) etc. the next time.